# CSV Pandas PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, csv, numpy

**I have a CSV file that looks like this**

```
S1,    22,   MD  , 0.022, ,  523.324
S2,    22,   MD  , 4.32,  , 342.54 
S3,    22,   MD  , 3.54,  ,   0.32
S4,    22,   MD  , 4.32,  ,  0.54  
S1,    33,   MD  , 5.32,  ,  0.43
S2,    33,   MD  , 11.54, ,  0.65
S3,    33,   MD  , 22.5,  ,  0.324
S4,    33,   MD  , 45.89  ,  0.32
S1,    44,  MD  , 3.53   ,  3.32
S2,    44,  MD  ,  4.5   ,  0.322
S3,    44,  MD  , 43.65  ,   45.78
S4,    44,   MD,   43.54 , 0.321
```

The file doesn't have any headers, however I do not care about the **MD** column

I need for my output file to look like this:

```
 Size ,   S1` ,    S2  ,   S3  ,   S4   

  22   ,  0.022 ,  4.32 ,  45.89 ,  4.32

  33  ,  5.32,    11.54 ,  22.5,   45.89, 

  44  ,  3.53,    4.5,     43.65,  43.54

        3 values, 3 values, 3,values, 3 values
```

As you can see the output file includes headers. Also the last row indicates the total number of values in each column.

My code thus far:

> > > import pandas as pd
> > >
> > > import numpy as np
> > >
> > > import csv
> > >
> > > df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\file.csv',usecols=[0,1,2,3,4])
> > >
> > > df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(['Names','FileSize','x','y','z'],df.columns)) *#add column headers... (this did not do it correctly)*
> > >
> > > df_out=df.groupby('Names','FileSize').count().reset_index() *#suppose to print distinct values*
> > >
> > > df_out.to_csv('processed_data_out.csv', columns['Names','FileSize','x','y','z'], header=False,index=False)

**I did not use the last column in my output because that column should be generated if the user asks to see that information. Which again I am having trouble doing.**

Comment: what have you tried/done so far? Also is your csv comma or space separated?

Comment: You've described your file and explained your requirements, but what is your question?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok Sorry. I was in a rush. I have tried using pandas, but it is looking at all the columns and not just the TSD and REquirement columns.

Comment: I have edit my question also for those who could not understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Pandas` approach is pretty nice for this.

Read data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data_in.csv', names=['Label','Requirements'], skiprows=1) # This assumes and skips the header row ('TSD' in your question)

>>> df
   Label  Requirements
0      A             1
1      A             2
2      A             3
3      A             4
4      A             5
5      B            11
6      B            22
7      B            45
8      C           NaN
9      C           NaN
10     C           NaN
```

Count requirements:

```
df_out = df.groupby('Label').count().reset_index()

>>> df_out
  Label  Requirements
0     A             5
1     B             3
2     C             0
```

Format to your needs:

```
df_out['Output'] = df_out.apply(lambda row: '%s doesn\'t have any requirement'%(row['Label']) if row['Requirements']==0 else '%s has %d requirements'%(row['Label'],row['Requirements']), axis=1)

>>> df_out
  Label  Requirements                          Output
0     A             5            A has 5 requirements
1     B             3            B has 3 requirements
2     C             0  C doesn't have any requirement
```

Export to CSV:

```
df_out.to_csv('processed_data_out.csv', columns=['Output'], header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: How would I parse the csv in pandas.

Comment: The `pd.read_csv(...)` part will read in the csv for you. Based on your edited question, since your file doesn't have any headers and the columns are Script, TSD, Requirement, you would use the following: `names=['Script','TSD','Requirement']`. If you do have a header row in the first row, you can remove the `skiprows=1` part. The rest of the functionality in my answer will work the same.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {}
with open(your_file, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line_list = line.split(' ')
        if len(line_list) == 2:
            key, requirement = line_list
            if key in my_dict:
                my_dict[key] += 1
            else:
                my_dict[key] = 0
        elif len(line_list) == 1:
            key = line_list[0]
            if key not in my_dict:
                my_dict[key] = 0
```

And then write the dictionary `my_dict` to another csv file...

EDIT: this is assuming you have a space-separated file, but you can change the separator in `line.split(' ')` by any separator...